# install nodejs and npm on ubuntu 21.10, install sucessful but showing wrong version with "node -v"

Tags: nodejs

I am new to js and wanted to install nodejs LTS version and npm on ubuntu 21.10. So, I followed the nodesources repository install instructions and it had stated to use the install script for LTS and it worked fine as I followed the same instructions mentioned in it.

But, after installation of the nodejs package, when I try to check the node -v: it shows as 12.x.x, while the latest LTS version for nodejs is 16.x.x. I did not understand why this is happening and what is the solution for this?

P.S: I have mentioned the commands that I had used for installation of nodejs LTS 16.x.x, and the site link is this: https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/blob/master/README.md

### cmd:

```
Node.js LTS (v16.x):

# Using Ubuntu
curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_lts.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

Please note: I have not installed the optional build tools yet and not the npm as well. I'm confused on what to do now...

Answer (score 0):

The first command there adds new repositories which apt-get will use when you request nodejs to be installed. I guess that the first command failed for whatever reason (perhaps you didn't copy the entire line including the `-`, perhaps you typed the password wrong). As a result, the second command gave you the ubuntu-system-default version of node.

My recommendation to you now is to install and use `nvm` to install whatever node version you want. You can follow the installation instructions here https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm. With nvm, you can install and switch between node installations that are user-local, for example:

```bash
$ nvm install 17
$ node -v
v17.9.1
$ which node
~/.nvm/versions/node/v17.9.1/bin/node
```